# Календарь не выводится на экран.

Tags: java-me, java, мобильные-приложения

Здравствуйте, помогите исправить ошибку в коде. Программа рабочая, ошибок нет, но результат ее работы не выводится в эмуляторе среды Java ME Platform SDK.

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class  kalendar extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {
     private Display mydisplay;
    private String[] str = { "гггг.мм.дд", "дд.мм.гггг", "гггг-мм-дд", "гггг.мм.дд hh:mm" };
    private Command myexit = new Command("Выход", Command.EXIT, 0);
    private Command action = new Command("показать", Command.ITEM, 1);
    private ChoiceGroup operation = new ChoiceGroup(null, ChoiceGroup.POPUP, str, null);
    private StringItem myresult = new StringItem("показать", null);
    private Form myform = new Form("календарь");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    public kalendar()
    {
       mydisplay = Display.getDisplay(this);
    }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean arg0)
    {
    }
    protected void pauseApp()
    {
    }

    protected void startApp()
    {
       myform.append(operation);
       myform.append(myresult);
       myform.addCommand(myexit);
       myform.addCommand(action);
       myform.setCommandListener(this);
       mydisplay.setCurrent(myform);
    }
    public void commandAction(Command arg0, Displayable arg1)
    {

        if (arg0 == myexit)
        {
            destroyApp(false);
            notifyDestroyed();
        }
        if (arg0 == action)
        {
                switch (operation.getSelectedIndex())
                {
                case 0:
       myform.append (year+"."+(month+1)+"."+ day);
                    break;
                case 1:
        myform.append (day+"."+(month+1)+"."+year);
                    break;
                case 2:
       myform.append (year+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+day);
                    break;
                case 3:
        myform.append (year+"."+(month+1)+"."+day+" "+hour+":"+minute);
                    break;
                }

            myresult.setText(null);
          }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызовите в конце `commanAction()`  `mydisplay.setCurrent(myform)` - по моему надо было так... запамятовал уже.

P.S. Комментарии по коду:

1. Не `public class kalendar`, а `public class Kalendar`, а еще лучше `public class CalendarMidlet` - [Java Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) никто не отменял
2. Удивляюсь, что есть еще люди пишущие под J2ME - вроде технология уже умерла